# Bootstrap 4 Modal won't open in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 4 modal works fine on browsers except Internet Explorer...I tried removing the fade class with no luck, I also tried a JS solution

```
 $(function () {
  var isIE = window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window;
if (isIE) {
    $('.modal').removeClass('fade');
}
});



  <!-- MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-video" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="modal-video-label">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-video">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <video id="sample-video" controls>
                        <source src="video/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser is not supported
                      </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--END MODAL -->
```

still no luck....anyone run into this and find a working solution???

CONSOLE ERROS WHEN CLICKING BUTTON:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.3.1.js:1541)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery-3.3.1.js:2193)
at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.3.1.js:2620)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.3.1.js:845)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.3.1.js:2873)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-3.3.1.js:2983)
at jQuery (jquery-3.3.1.js:139)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (script.js:30)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)
```

Comment: If you remove fade manually, does the modal open correctly?

Comment: still did not work....strange....only IE OF COURSE...lol

Comment: IE 11, right? Update please

Comment: Yes, IE 11.....On EDGE it works fine

Comment: So then the issue isn't fade. Are you getting any errors in your console? Have you googled around, to find out if others are having this issue?

Comment: Yes I have done some googling on the issue and found some solutions but they did not seem to work and yes I am getting errors in the console when I click the "Watch Video" button...I'll post above

Comment: Did you try already try to toggle the modal using JavaSscript? Using `$('#modal-video').modal('toggle')`? Could probably give you hint whether it is supported at all?

Comment: Just tried that.....modal was not opening on page load in IE but other browsers opened with the modal opened when using 
$('#modal-video').modal('toggle')